# Bash script. Insert a blank line before a number range

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need a bash script to format a text file. It must add a blank line before a range of numbers. 
Something like the examples in the images below. I am trying:

```
sed '1{x;d};$H;/^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|[1-4][0-9]{3}|5000)$/{x;s/^/\n/;b};x '/home/name/zxc' > vvvv
```

but it does't run.

Thanks in advance.

[source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbmR9.png)

[target screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2rxc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would this work for you:

```
 sed '/^[0123456789]\+$/{x;p;x;}' < input.txt
```

From http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

```
 # double space a file
 sed G

 # double space a file which already has blank lines in it. Output file
 # should contain no more than one blank line between lines of text.
 sed '/^$/d;G'

 # triple space a file
 sed 'G;G'

 # undo double-spacing (assumes even-numbered lines are always blank)
 sed 'n;d'

 # insert a blank line above every line which matches "regex"
 sed '/regex/{x;p;x;}'

 # insert a blank line below every line which matches "regex"
 sed '/regex/G'

 # insert a blank line above and below every line which matches "regex"
 sed '/regex/{x;p;x;G;}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sehe, it runs fine. ;-))

Comment: Hi sehe, very kind of you.
I try upvote but I get a pop that I need 15 reputation before.

Comment: This is why it's important to upvote questions, not just answers.

Comment: Upvote, although `sed` is not the best tool here. And I like the fact that somebody upvoted your comment about accepting answers - but did not upvote this answer.

Comment: @sehe, And besides I like `awk`/`sed` and bourne scripting, it's available everywhere. I do use `Python` when it's available, however, often where I work I find it to be the exception and not the rule.